# Check If User get Role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want that as soon as someone gets a role, they get a second role at the same time. I have seen that it can work with on_member_update, but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: Your question in unclear, try to modify it: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by listening to the [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event. This event takes two paramers; `before: discord.Member` and `after: discord.Member`. `before` is the updated member before the update, and `after` is the updated member.
What you need to do is check if `before.roles` doesn't contain the role you're listening to, and if `after.roles` contains the role you're listening to. If this is the case, it means that the role you're listening to has just been given to the member, so we'll give our second role to that user using the [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) function.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot: commands.Bot
LISTENING_ROLE: discord.Role
GIVEN_ROLE: discord.Role

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member) -> None:
    if LISTENING_ROLE not in before.roles and LISTENING_ROLE in after.roles:
        # User has just received the `ROLE_WHICH_WE_ARE_LISTENING_TO` role.
        # Time to give them the second role.
        await after.add_roles(
            GIVEN_ROLE,
            reason="This message will appear in the audit logs."
        )
```